What is this snail?
A week earlier I added one plant (2 stems of Cambomba) in my pond and there was a small creature clinging on a stem. I did not remove it in the hopes of getting a new specie. Now it has got bigger and looks like a snail.
I already have couple of ramshorn in my tank and I am trying to increase its population. So I don't want to introduce a snail species that would outcompete ramshorn for food. Also don't want assassin snails to kill my ramshorns :C
Please help identify this snail. It has a dark body with (what appears to be) one yellow stripe.

